# Design decision behind entry to an API

Tags: java, api, oop

I am new to creating an API for others to use. And I was thinking about the design decisions that go behind creating the entry to an API.

Like JAXB uses a class called `JAXBContext` as an entry point to use its framework, Mockito uses the class `Mockito` itself as the entry point and has whole lots of static methods for that.

So are there any thumb rules to be kept in mind when designing an API ?

EDIT:
The API does the work of reading and reloading the configurations from different sources.

Comment: What kind of API are you making?

Comment: No matter what you do **Document Everything**. You could have written the best code in the world but if you don't have docs I won't go near it.

Comment: @jozefg surely. But I mean I am stumped thinking about the extension of API and whether present design will prove to be nightmare tomorrow.

Comment: This is a tough question to answer because it's not about one specific problem. There are entire books on this. I'd suggest searching for 'Framework Design Guidelines' at amazon.com. There's a good .NET book there, but you'll get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to design your API as a service loadable with [`ServiceLoader`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ServiceLoader.html), similar to DOM API. Thus, your API will be loadable as:

```
Entry entry = ServiceLoader.load(Entry.class).next();
```

And it will be easy to have many implementations of the same API.